# Hybris OOB code how to access the OOB code in development

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, expert-system

I have set the code for CC mail, but there is one AbstractEmailContext file (which is OOB file) where I have defined the CC mail parameter. If I create a new one like that file, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get question correctly, but I just wanted to point out the [details article](https://www.helphybris.com/2018/03/multiple-toaddress-attachment-in-email-hybris.html) where I have demonstrated all changes to support ToAddresses, CC, BCC, attachment etc in Hybris

Answer (score 0):

`CC email` is set in `EmailMessageModel` when `getEmailService().createEmailMessage()` is called. There is no reason to set `CC email` in `AbstractEmailContext`